# Ha-proxy config suggestions

Tags: haproxy

In Haproxy, I have a requirement to serve a context "foo"
with URL.

```
abc.example.com
```

it gets served fine, if I use URL as

```
abc.example.com/foo
```

However as this ha proxy is shared with other customers and by default the health checking has been configured with monitor-URI

```
 monitor-uri /
```

Whenever I am using abc.example.com it gets served with default 200 OK service ready page. it does not go to any ACL for routing to backend.

For example:-

```
acl host_example hdr(host) -i example.com.com
use_backend example_cluster if host_example
```

Is there any workaround, suggestion apart from changing monitor-URI ?

Answer (score 0):

When you request abc.example.com you are requesting the root URI "/", this is exactly where your monitor-uri is positioned. So you will get the monitor reply and nothing else.
You need to change your monitor-uri to something else like "monitor-uri /haproxy" or move the monitor-uri to different port.